# PyBullet cannot load urdf file

Tags: python, filepath, pybullet

When I try running an example PyBullet file, like the one below, I keep getting the following error message:

```
import pybullet as p
from time import sleep
import pybullet_data

physicsClient = p.connect(p.GUI)

p.setAdditionalSearchPath(pybullet_data.getDataPath())
p.setGravity(0, 0, -10)
planeId = p.loadURDF("plane.urdf", [0,0,-2])
boxId = p.loadURDF("cube.urdf", [0,3,2],useMaximalCoordinates = True)
bunnyId = p.loadSoftBody("bunny.obj")#.obj")#.vtk")

useRealTimeSimulation = 1

if (useRealTimeSimulation):
    p.setRealTimeSimulation(1)

p.changeDynamics(boxId,-1,mass=10)
while p.isConnected():
    p.setGravity(0, 0, -10)
    if (useRealTimeSimulation):

        sleep(0.01)    # Time in seconds.
    else:
        p.stepSimulation()
```

The error shows as following:

> bunnyId = p.loadSoftBody("bunny.obj")#.obj")#.vtk")

> error: Cannot load soft body.

I have Windows 10. I'm running PyBullet on a notebook (Python 3.6), but I get the same error with Visual Studio (Python 3.7). What can I do to fix it?

Comment: `bunny.obj` does not seem to be part of pybullet_data (see `ls $(python3 -c "import pybullet_data; print(pybullet_data.getDataPath());")`), so you need to provide it separately.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solved issue in https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3/pull/4010#issue-1035353580,
either upgrade pybullet or copy the .obj file from the repository to `pybullet_data` directory will be fine.